# Swift 2: Writing to plist with multidimensional objects

Tags: arrays, object, swift2, plist

I am a newbie in Swift and I have been trying something for a long time and I am having an compile error that could not overcome with.

I am trying to write to a plist containing multidimensional array objects.

I need to add an array to the inner array of plist.

The plist is like as follows:

[image: plist]

I am trying to populate the most inner array of the plist which is as follows:

[image]

I am trying to add `ITEM 2` under the `ITEM 5`.

I am using this code:

```
notesArray.objectAtIndex(0).objectAtIndex(5).addObject("AA","BB","CC","DD")
```

Compiler gives me following error :

> Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyObject) -> Void)!'

How can I populate the array inside the parent array directly from the code?

Answer (score 1):

Due to value semantics of Swift arrays you have to reassign all changes to their parent objects

This is the initial array

```
var array : [AnyObject] = [["OZEN PIZZA", "PIZZA", "15", "20", "tariffoto1", [["Biber","2", "Adet", "11"]]]]
```

get the root array at index 0 of the array

```
var rootArray = array[0] as! [AnyObject]
```

get the array at index 5 of `rootArray`

```
var item5Array = rootArray[5] as! [[String]]
```

append the item

```
item5Array.append(["AA","BB","CC","DD"])
```

reassign `item5Array` to index 5 of `rootArray`

```
rootArray[5] = item5Array
```

reassign `rootArray` to index 0 of the array

```
array[0] = rootArray
```

Comment: Hi there, i will try them and reply to you As soon as possible. Thank you very much Sir